# Spring boot + Freemarker + Bootstrap, submit form select option Entity as value

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, freemarker

I have a spring-boot web application that works with freemarker template engine and uses Twitter bootstrap for styling.

I have an issue with saving entity through submit form.

My entity Category looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
@NotNull
private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
private Category parentCategory;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory")
private Set<Category> subCategories;}
```

as you can see it has self reference.

My Controller for saving this entity.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category, Model model) {
        categoryService.save(category);
        return "categories";
    }
```

And for creating form for new Category

```
@RequestMapping("/new")
public String newCategory(Model model) {
    List<Category> allCategories = categoryService.getCategories();
    model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
    model.addAttribute("allCategories", allCategories);
    return "category_new";
}
```

finally in my FTL template file I have (I'l post only part for single select)

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="parentCategory">Parent</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="parentCategory" name="parentCategory">
                    <option value="">-- None --</option>
                <#list allCategories as value>
                    <option value="${value}">${value.name}</option>
                </#list>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now when new form renders everything is ok. Select options are populated nicely.
Like so:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="parentCategory">Parent</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="parentCategory" name="parentCategory">
                    <option value="">-- None --</option>
                    <option value="Entity of type rs.app.web.portal.model.Category with id: 1">Cat 1</option>
                    <option value="Entity of type rs.app.web.portal.model.Category with id: 2">Cat 2</option>
                    <option value="Entity of type rs.app.web.portal.model.Category with id: 3">Cat 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but when I submit form I dont get anything for property parentCategory. There is no error in console. For other properties of Category like 'name' which is String, everything works fine. I get value populated in input. But I cant seem to get selected Parent category ... 
How do I post Entity as a property on sumbisson form???

Thanks.